# Failed to bind data to grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a webmethod that returns data to the js side of my code. I want to bind the data and display it on the grid.

```
function LoadData(){
 var data = GetDataFromWebMethod();
if (data === undefined || data == null) {
 $('#DisplayGrid').next().append('<span id="spnErr"> No Data.</span>');
}
else {
        var configData = [];
        configData.push({ label: "EmpName", name: 'EmpName', width: 300, sopt: ['cn'] });
        configData.push({ label: "Dept", name: 'Dept', width: 300, sopt: ['cn'] });
}

function GetRelatedWorkitem() {
 ajaxSync("POST", "/WebServices/Page.asmx/GetData", "application/json; charset=utf-8", "json", JSON.stringify({ Emp: name}), doneCallBack, failCallback);
    return objData.Data;
}
```

Comment: Any javascript errors in browser developer console?

Comment: I believe my LoadData() is incomplete . I havent bound it to the grid.

Comment: @Learner look at the [bind code](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/auto-table-structure/) in this link